# Make a html element appear clickable with JQuery / JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is it possible to make an html element appear clickable with JQuery?

By appear clickable I mean have the mouse pointer change appearance when the user hovers over the the element.

I dont want to use a  tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
jQuery('myelement').css("cursor", "pointer");
```

This can also be done in pure CSS with `cursor:pointer`.

Comment: Or, in modern times: `$("myelement").css("cursor", "pointer");`, but it's always better to use CSS unless you have a reason to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 6):

You don't do this with Javascript, you do it with CSS:

```
.whatever {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

You could do the same thing with jQuery if you *really* wanted, but all you're really doing is setting up the style:

```
$(".whatever").css("cursor", "pointer");
```

Answer (score 2):

You use the CSS [`cursor`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/ui.html#cursor-props) property for this. Directly with CSS:

```
#id { cursor: pointer; }
```

Or with jQuery using [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/category/css/):

```
$("#id").css("cursor", "pointer");
```

Or with Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("id").style.cursor = "pointer";
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the style of the element to:

```
#elementId {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

You could do it with jQuery, but not sure why you'd want to? Here 'tis:

```
$(this).css("cursor", "pointer");
```